# I can not run Django Python pytest under PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, pytest, pytest-django

```
$ pytest portal/
=============================================== test session starts ===============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.0, pytest-3.0.6, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
Django settings: config.settings.local (from ini file)
rootdir: /Users/el/Code/siam-sbrand/portal, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-3.1.2
collected 87 items

portal/apps/commons/tests.py ......
portal/apps/price_list_excel_files/tests.py ssssssssssss
portal/apps/price_lists/tests.py s....
portal/apps/reports/tests.py .........................ssss..................
portal/apps/sbrand_jobs/tests.py ................
portal/apps/service_items/tests.py s

===================================== 69 passed, 18 skipped in 32.08 seconds ======================================
```

**pytest.ini:**

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.local
norecursedirs = node_modules venv *.txt
python_files = tests.py Test*.py test_*.py
```

I have install `pytest-django` under `pyenv` already. Then I want to study key feature in PyCharm, but unfortunately when I try reaching the JetBrain forum. It is limited to the company owner only. I can not post my question because I just an employee.

[image]

And this is when I click play `pytest` button

```
/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/bin/python pytest portal
/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/bin/python: can't open file 'pytest': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

**Update refer to `falsetru` answer
[image]

[image]

Yeah! It works like a `PyCharm`. It is not green light because I put decorator `skip` in my test. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `python`, You should use `Python tests > py.test`:

[image: py.test configuration on PyCharm]

---

**UPDATE**

You filtered test result to show only skipped test. Toggle green button will show also successful tests.

[image: toggle this buttons]

Comment: OK. One moment. I am following your reply.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you don't mind answering to newbie like me I am still have a question. I will update my post and ask in the same question

Comment: @Sarit, You're welcome. BTW, your new question is a related, but different question, isn't it? Please post a separate question instead of extending original question.

Comment: Thank you. After short moment of clicking through the icons. I found it is my skip cases.

Comment: I post new question already. It is same topic, but different framework. If you would like to have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868381/setting-pycharm-run-django-unittest