# Setting pycharm run django unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm, django-unittest

[I can not run Django Python pytest under PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868078/i-can-not-run-django-python-pytest-under-pycharm/44868137#44868137) 
After I got the answer from the above URL. I am now trying to fully utilize my IDE functions as much as I can.
Here is another project in my company that using `Django UnitTest`. This is the command line I used.
`$ python manage.py test --settings=eneos.config.settings.local`
Actually `--settings=eneos.config.settings.local` is not required, because I put that config in the `wsgi.py` already. But explicit is better than implicit when I ask the question.

[image]

Unfortunately. It is not simple like `pytest`. I must miss some points in here.

First several lines in the window.

```
/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/eneos-pos-web/bin/python "/Users/el/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/171.4694.38/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py" --path .
Testing started at 2:17 PM ...
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest discover -s . -t /Users/el/Code/eneos-pos-web in /Users/el/Code/eneos-pos-web
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

[image]

**Update:**
[image]
It used to ask me with Exclamation mark and let me fix the path in the bottom right. Just put working directory and configuration file in the asking form.

[image]
Done!

Comment: There's a `Django test` run configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`Django tests` run configuration.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-django-test.html)

[image: Django tests]

Using that, you can set Django-specific options; `Custom settings`, for example.

Comment: Holy Sh.t. I was reading on this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/ and it direct me to `unittest`!. Hold on one moment. I will get back to forum

Comment: But that is only for professional edition tho

Comment: @swdev,Yes, only professional edition support python web frameworks. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: @falsetru for now I think I am quite satisfied with pytest-django in pycharm community. no click on error source code level, but good enough. At least there is an UI for that